# Loss of sharpness in jpg imported as header in twentyeleven

Tags: images, custom-header

When importing a jpg into the header position (jpg created in indesign at 1000 px wide) for the twentyeleven theme, the photos are not sharp. what is causing this and how do I fix it?

Comment: Are you resizing the image in the browser?

Comment: http://wordpress.org/plugins/imagemagick-engine/

Answer (score 1):

Before hitting the button "use this media", have you checked "Full Size" in the Size option?

It's basic, but at times one skips over this things without realizing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One issue might be the file type you're using.  JPG is best for photorealistic images, but if you're producing something in inDesign you are likely creating something more "graphic" (like a custom font treatment with some drawn boxes, patterns, and solid colors), and for anything other than photorealistic images you'll get your clearest result saving the file as a PNG -- which will also resize with the most sharp/true fidelity to the original.

Regardless, Ordago's answer about "use this media" checking "Full Size" is an essential step.